# Unable to animate elements in correct order?

Tags: jquery

I have a problem where the fadeout waits for animations to end before it starts fading out, even though it should fade out first.

Any way to make it happen at the same time?

```
$('.hover-div').mouseout(function() {

        $('div.hidden').fadeOut(); // this happens AFTER the following animations are done

        $('.carousel-bg').animate({
            'top': 112,
            'height': 130
        }, 200);

        $('div.carousel-holder div.text').animate({
            'top': 125
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide an isolated example with your problem?

Comment: Not really. It happens on a page where some  plugin is used and there's just too much. In any case, is it possible to have the 2 happen at the same time is pretty much the question.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but it shouldn't behave like that, even if it's queued the first called animation should run first, and it's only queued that way if it's the same element, so something else is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Manage your displaying speed in `milliseconds` Try this :-

```
    $('div.hidden').fadeOut(50);

    $('.carousel-bg').animate({
        'top': 112,
        'height': 130
    }, 200);

    $('div.carousel-holder div.text').animate({
        'top': 125
    }, 200);
```

Comment: can you please explain a bit about your answer.?

Comment: Its just a speed difference..!! Simple

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.hover-div').mouseout(function() {


        $('.carousel-bg').animate({
            'top': '112px',
            'height': '130px'
        }, 200);

        $('div.carousel-holder div.text').animate({
            'top': '125px'
        }, function() {  $('div.hidden').fadeOut(); });
    });
```

Comment: This will fadeOut at the very end...He wants it at the beginning.